# method overriding

Tags: java

```
class A
{
  int i=10;
  void show()
  {
    System.out.println("class A");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  int i=5;
  public void show()
  {
    System.out.println("class B");
  }
}
class M
{
  public static void main(String s[])
  {
    A a=new B();
    a.show();
    System.out.println(a.i);
  }
}


OUTPUT= class B
        10
```

If class A method is overridden by class B method then why not the variable 'i'?

Comment: check my note about your class declaration

Answer (score 5):

Because variables are not virtual, only methods are.

Comment: "virtual" is C++ terminology, we don't call methods (or variables) "virtual" in Java.

Comment: His sentence still means the same thing if he said "overridden" instead - same meaning.

Comment: @matt b, I think it means "overriddable" but I'm not sure if there is such word :)

Answer (score 5):

It is not overwritten, but hidden. In your output you specifically requested the value of a.i, not ((B)a).i.

Comment: Why no field overrides in Java though? Because instance field lookups in Java happen at compile time: Java simply gives you the value of the field at a given offset, computed at compile time, in object's memory (based on the type information at hand during compilation: in this case `a` is declared to be of type `A`).

Comment: Ook, @vava. I have used this comment as a basis of a more expanded answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a "feature" of the implementation. In memory, this looks like so:

```
a:
    pointer to class A
    int i

b:
    pointer to class B
    int i (from A)
    int i (from B)
```

When you access `i` in an instance of `B`, Java needs to know which variable you mean. It must allocate both since methods from class `A` will want to access their own field `i` while methods from `B` will want their own `i` (since you chose to create a new field `i` in `B` instead of making `A.i` visible in `B`). This means there are two `i` and the standard visibility rules apply: Whichever is closer will win.

Now you say `A a=new B();` and that's a bit tricky because it tells Java "treat the result from the right hand side as if it were an instance of `A`".

When you call a method, Java follows the pointer to the class (first thing in the object in memory). There, it finds a list of methods. Methods overwrite each other, so when it looks for the method `show()`, it will find the one defined in `B`. This makes method access fast: You can simply merge all visible methods in the (internal) method list of class `B` and each call will mean a single access to that list. You don't need to search all classes upwards for a match.

Field access is similar. Java doesn't like searching. So when you say `B b = new B();`, `b.i` is obviously from `B`. But you said `A a = new B()` telling Java that you prefer to treat the new instance as something of type `A`. Java, lazy as it is, looks into `A`, finds a field `i`, checks that you can see that field and doesn't even bother to look at the real type of `a` anymore (because that would a) be slow and b) would effectively prevent you from accessing both `i` fields by casting).

So in the end, this is because Java optimizes the field and method lookup.

Comment: Does it mean that if you write B b = new B() and then call any of the methods from A that weren't overridden in B, i would be 10 inside those methods as the call comes from B type?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Methods get the value from the class they are implemented in.

Comment: For any method that is defined in `A`, the value of `i`  will be 10. For any method that was defined in `B`, it's 5. Inside of the class, the closest definition of `i` wins: Local variable, field in same class, field in super class (in this order).

Comment: You can access `A.i` from inside of `B` by using `super.i`. Outside of the classes, you can't use `super`, though. So Java needs a way to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 3):

Why no field overrides in Java though?

Well, because instance field lookups in Java happen at compile time: Java simply gives you the value of the field at a given offset in object's memory (based on the type information at hand during compilation: in this case a is declared to be of type A).

```
void foo() {
  A a = new B();
  int val = a.i; // compiler uses type A to compute the field offset
}
```

One may ask "Why didn't compiler use type `B` since it knows that `a` is in fact an instance of `B`? Isn't it obvious from the assignment just above?". Of course, in the case above, it's relatively obvious and compiler may try to be smarter and figure it out.

But that's compiler design "rat hole", what if a "trickier" piece of code is encountered, like so:

```
void foo(A a) {
  int val = a.i;
}
```

If compiler *were* "smarter", it would become its job to look at all invocations of `foo()` and see what real type was used, which is an impossible job since compiler can not predict what other crazy things may be passed to `foo()` by unknown or yet unwritten callers.

Comment: Anyway, smarter coding(i.e. int getI() { return i; }) solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a design decision by the developers of Java, and is documented in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).

A method with the same method signature as a method in its parent class [overrides](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#227927) the method in its parent class.

A variable with the same name as a variable in its parent class [hides](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.3.2) the parent's variable.

The difference is that hidden values can be accessed by casting the variable to its parent type, while overridden methods will always execute the child class's method.

As others have noted, in C++ and C#, to get the same override behavior as Java, the methods need to be declared virtual.

Answer (score -1):

`a` is an instance of A. You call the constructor B(). But it is still a `A` class.
That is why i equals 10;
The override from the method will be succeded.

Note a class starts not with

```
public class A()
```

but with;

```
public class A { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Tip:** You can use setters and getters to make sure of what data-members you use.
**Or:** You simply can set the values at the constructor instead of the class declaration.

Answer (score -3):

Because by default the variables are private. You must declare it as "protected", then will be properly inherited.

Comment: Default visibility of variables and methods in java classes is visible to all other classes in the same package, not private.